# Landing page with ExpressionEngine's built-in Member module?

Tags: expressionengine

ExpressionEngine comes shipped with a Member module out of the box. Profiles are viewable at a URL like **http://domain.com/member/profile/123**; however, there's no "landing" page for members—everything's at a URL built on top of members, i.e. **http://domain.com/member/memberlist**.

I've wanting to create a landing page for logged-in members at **http://domain.com/member**. Currently, navigating to this URL just returns the following error:

> **The following errors were encountered**
>
> - The member profile you requested is currently not available
>
> Return to Previous Page

How can I create a page or template that would be displayed when navigating to **/member** instead of the default error page? As it looks like it's expecting another parameter to display a profile page, but this isn't desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Martin,
Out of the box you don't have many options. Using something like Zoo Member or Solspace User will allow you to break away from the defaults and customise your landing page.

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for. I'm aware there are improved third-party alternatives out there, but project constraints mean I'm not able to purchase these.

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be on /member/?

If it does, why not change the profile_trigger word in the config file this:

```
$config['profile_trigger'] = 'members'
```

Then you can create a template group called "member" and put whatever in the index.html there, since now /members/ is reserved for the profile templates. Of course navigating to /members/ would give the same error so you'd have to change all links that go directory to /members/ to /member/ (in profile_themes/default or whatever theme you're using)

Comment: I want it to be the root of whatever I use as my trigger. So literally the trigger word and no additional segments would display my dashboard/landing page.

Comment: Ok, that is not possible using EE's default member module. You'd have to work around it either by doing it in templates as I suggested above, or you can create an addon which hooks onto sessions_start() and then changes the template to be triggered on /member/

Answer (score 0):

Not tested this, but could you just create a template group /member/ and then use the `{exp:member:custom_profile_data}` tag? See:

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/member/index.html#custom-profile-data-tag

You could then pass in the `{logged_in_member_id}` global variable (or other member id variable) to this tag. e.g.

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{logged_in_member_id}"}
   <p>{age}, {gender}</p>
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

In fact, I believe the custom_profile_data tag uses the currently logged in member id as the default anyway.

Apologies if I've misunderstood your question though.